# I have a question on implementing singly linked list

Tags: javascript, singly-linked-list

I have a question on implementing singly linked list.

I am implementing the push method.

Please look at the code first. (This code is not working properly.)

```
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    push(val) {
        let newNode = new Node(val);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
        }
        this.length++;
        return this;
    }
}

let list = new SinglyLinkedList()

list.push(1)
list.push(2)
```

The results of the above code are as follows.

```
{
    "head": {
        "val": 1,
        "next": {
            "val": 2,
            "next": null
        }
    },
    "tail": {
        "val": 1,
        "next": {
            "val": 2,
            "next": null
        }
    },
    "length": 2
}
```

I don't understand this process.

in the else statement

'this.tail.next = newNode;'

, but why is the value added to head.next as well?

I thought. 'Is it because they refer to the same node through an if statement?'

But that doesn't seem to be the reason either.

Please see the code below.

```
    push(val) {
        let newNode = new Node(val);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        }
        this.length++;
        return this;
    }
```

The code above is the code with

'this.tail = newNode;'

added to the else statement.

The results are as follows.

```
{
    "head": {
        "val": 1,
        "next": {
            "val": 2,
            "next": null
        }
    },
    "tail": {
        "val": 2,
        "next": null
    },
    "length": 2
}
```

And this code works the push method perfectly.

If "head.next" has changed due to "tail.next", shouldn't "head" also change when changing "tail"?
Why did only "tail" change this time?

To sum up, the question is this.

Why does "head.next" change when "tail.next" changes?

confused...I can't follow the flow of this code...

Comment: When you `.push()` a new value and the head is not null, then when you set `this.tail.next` to the new node, you must then also set `this.tail` to the new node.

Comment: And when `head` and `tail` are both pointing at the same object, then of course changes to one will change the other. You could test for that in the `.push()` logic if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting your `if` into more straightforward logic. For example, your `tail` doesn't actually depend on the `head`. I agree that indirectly, if `head` is not set, it probably means that the `tail` is not set, too, but I wouldn't make such assumptions in the code. And the last thing is that you want to update `tail` always unconditionally.

Check the code below and check the console log that looks like so:

```
{
  "head": {
    "val": 1,
    "next": {
      /**id:3**/
      "val": 2,
      "next": null
    }
  },
  "tail": /**ref:3**/,
  "length": 2
}
```

Notice that 2nd node is shown with `id:3` in the `next` and then as `ref:3` in the tail because it was added as `next` first and then referenced from the `tail`.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    push(val) {
        let newNode = new Node(val);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        if (this.tail) {
          this.tail.next = newNode;
        }
        this.tail = newNode;        
        this.length++;
        return this;
    }
}

let list = new SinglyLinkedList()

list.push(1)
list.push(2)

console.log(list);
```